# Method and variable name is the same

Tags: ruby

If both a method and a variable has the same name it will use the variable.

```
hello = "hello from variable"

def hello
  "hello from method"
end

puts hello
```

Is it possible somehow to use the method instead without changing name?

Comment: @Henrik: I want to know ruby better

Comment: This very thing (among many other great things) is mentioned in a book called "Ruby In A Nutshell" by Yukihiro Matsumoto (the creator of Ruby); published by O'Reilly). The book is great for answering exactly the sort of depth of question you asked.

Comment: @Henrik: See my "answer" as an example of why you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
puts hello()
```

Comment: Right, but please elaborate on why using the parentheses make this work

Comment: Because you are explicitly calling a method.  Better to just, you know, use different names in the first place...

Answer (score 19):

The ambiguity between local variables and methods only arises for receiverless message sends with no argument list. So, the solution is obvious: either provide a receiver or an argument list:

```
self.hello
hello()
```

See also

- [How does ruby allow a method and a Class with the same name?](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2985850/how-does-ruby-allow-a-method-and-a-class-with-the-same-name/2986338#2986338)
- [Optional parens in Ruby for method with uppercase start letter?](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2950956/optional-parens-in-ruby-for-method-with-uppercase-start-letter/2951439#2951439)

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but distinguishing between local variables and methods is vital if you're using an assignment method.

```
class TrafficLight
  attr_accessor :color

  def progress_color
    case color
    when :orange
      #Don't do this!
      color = :red
    when :green
      #Do this instead!
      self.color = :orange
    else
      raise NotImplementedError, "What should be done if color is already :red? Check with the domain expert, and build a unit test"
    end
  end
end

traffic_light = TrafficLight.new
traffic_light.color = :green
traffic_light.progress_color
traffic_light.color # Now orange
traffic_light.progress_color
traffic_light.color # Still orange
```

Answer (score 2):

```
puts self.hello
```

By the way, I agree with Henrik P. Hessel.
This is a very horrible piece of code.

Comment: I agree! This is a very horrible piece of code. :-)