# Why output is "Sorry" instead of "Hello"?

Tags: ruby

Why I am getting the output "Sorry" instead of "Hello" ? Please someone explain this.

```
output_hello = "Sorry"

def output_hello
  "Hello"
end

puts output_hello
```

Comment: Try `output_hello()`.

Comment: Why all the downvotes and closing the question? There's no way for them to know that there was a duplicate as they didn't know their problem

Comment: In your example output_hello is a variable, "Sorry", and a method called output_hello, which returns "Hello". When you call `output_hello` without the brackets, it references the variable. With the brackets, and you call the method instead

Comment: @Mark: That's *precisely* what closing as a duplicate is for. The question stays, so that people who don't know how to search for the duplicate can find this question instead, but all answers are collected in a single place, where they can be curated, ranked, and voted without fragmenting across many questions.

Comment: @Mark: It's even less effort to close-vote as a duplicate, *and* is a better result for the OP, because he gets a *proper* answer instead of someone "just writing a sentence". Even [*my* 9-year old, very short, very compressed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3741741/2988) is *two* sentences, plus two additional references.

Comment: I'm pretty curious who deleted my comment about how offputting this is for new users and how many people simply leave the site after getting their first question downvoted and closed for being a 'duplicate'.

Comment: @Mark: Comments are meant to be ephemeral. They can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In no way is my curiosity diminished by that fact.